# isEqualToSet not working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsset

I tried using isEqualToSet for comparing two sets based on a particular attribute as suggested in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116164/comparing-nssets-by-a-single-property/4116463#4116463). But after implementing the logic I found it wasn't working and I dint know the reason. It would be helpful if someone can suggest where I m going wrong or some alternative solution.. This is my code:

```
if([[[obj ofServer] valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToSet:[serverSet valueForKey:@"name"]])
{
   NSLog(@"handle both equal case");
}
NSLog(@"db log %@ and current logs server %@ \n",[[obj ofServer] valueForKey:@"name"],[serverSet valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

The output in console is showing the same set

```
db log {(
    "f7.net"
)} and current logs server {(
        (
        "f7.net"
    )
)}
```

Comment: Both are sets.. The only difference is serverSet is set formed from a mutableSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the log appears you have 2 different sets. 
I mean you are comparing

```
(
    "f7.net"
)
```

with

```
((
        "f7.net"
    ))
```

Hope this help

Comment: Basically I have to check for logs which have same set of servers.. I have stored logs and server in core data.. Both are one-many relationship. while checking I take log from file (as nsstring) and get servers (nsarray).. Since I dint know how to check a set's property value with array of strings I manually created a set of objects with the given servers.

Comment: Sorry I m not able to vote since i dnt have 15 reputation.. But consider this as my vote... :)